# Logging from swift in Macos app - where does it go?

Tags: macos, logging, swift5, macos-big-sur

I have a problem with an app I have written in Swift 5 on Macos Big Sur.

The problem is that a value is -1 and I can t find out where this is happening as I cant repeat this myself but the user can occasionally, but not occasionally enough that he can make it happen while I am watching!

So I need to look at the logs, no problem . . . except I dont know where the log goes on the released system.

I am using the LogDog library because it gives me the file and line number and works, I can see the log messages in XCode and I thought it would be written to the system log but no.

Using the console app the only log updated is the system log and I have inspected that and searched but can find no trace of the log messages.

I have googles for example code that I could test and adapt to my needs but I cant find anything.

I thought it might be that the app does not have the ability to write to a log but cant find anything on that, maybe googles does not like me?

To fix the bug I need the user to be able to call me when the problem happens so that I can download the log from his machine and find execution the path to the problem line.

I have tried displaying a dialogue with the stack trace but this proved to be too much for the user to cope with so having the data in the log that I can inspect at a latter date is the easiest option, if only I could get at the log messages!

Many thanks for any suggestions.